# Problem with Importing contact list from gmail contacts using php

Tags: gmail

I am trying to import the contact list from gmail using libgmailer.php but I am getting this error.

```
Fail to connect because: Gmail: Invalid request. (libgmailer: Gmail seems to have changed the URL again.)
```

Can anyone tell me what iam doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has an API to get the information now. http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/ Trying to screen-scrape the data is, at best, obsolete.